# Should I pluralize a channel's index slug?

Tags: url, slug

Lets say I have a channel called places, which has the following URL :

```
http://example.com/places
```

The url points to a directory of individual places.

However, when you click into an entry, each entry is a place, so it might make more sense to have each entry's url to be :

```
http:/example.com/place/place-name
```

Am I right in assuming that the best way to go about this would be to use a route for **`entries`**? Or is it best practice to keep things the same for consistency?

Comment: Follow-up question: what is common practice if you decide to keep them the same: `http://example.com/place` & `http:/example.com/place/place-name` or `http://example.com/places` & `http:/example.com/places/place-name`?

Comment: Plural is much more common.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn’t matter to Craft, but generally I think it’s better to have consistent URLs, so they can be discoverable. For example if you land on /places/place-name, it would be reasonable to assume that you could chop off “place-name” and find an index of all the places at /places/.

Comment: Yeah the more I think about it, the more I agree with you. Cheers!